MariaDB starting up without reading config file
Running into an issue which I'm sure is an easy fix, but I just can't find my way to it.  New installation of mariadb-server 11.4 on Ubuntu.
Have the installed default .cnf file in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
Starting the server via sudo systemctl start mariadb does NOT read this .cnf file. I'm specifically attempting to change the datadir, but I've even gone as far as adding an intentional syntax error in the file to prove that it's not being read/processed.
Starting the mariadb client via mariadb reads the .cnf file without a problem, it indicates the syntax error on line 4 as expected.
But starting via systemctl, doesn't change the datadir nor raises an error.
I've additionally added a /etc/mysql/my.cnf file just to be sure:
[mariadbd]
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

mariadbd --verbose --help returns
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
The following groups are read: mysqld server mysqld-11.4 mariadb mariadb-11.4 mariadbd mariadbd-11.4 client-server galera
.....
datadir                                                      /var/lib/mysql/

And lastly, the 50-server.cnf file is default other than the datadir line
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
xxxx # intentional syntax error

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mariadbd daemon
[mariadbd]

#
# * Basic Settings
#

#user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /mysql/data
#tmpdir                  = /tmp

<< remainder cut >>

Any suggestions?

check the file (or its directories) isn't group or other writeable but also make sure the file is readable by the mysql user. The easy way to check the last bit is with sudo -u mysql my_print_defaults --mariadbd so see what configuration options are read. Check journalctl -u mariadb.service -n 30, failing to read configuration files is normally a warning.
